# How to determine the vector dimension in C++?

Tags: python, c++, vector

In python, I got a list `'quad_list = ((len(D),4,2))'`, and `'len(D)'`is a 2 dimension list something like`' [[0,1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[3,4,5,6]]'`. Then if I want a same list in C++, that `'quad_list'` going to be `'std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> quad_list(D.size(),4,2)'`? so it is a 3 dimension vector, and what if I wanna insert some value to the vector, or just do something like `'for i, j in zip(D, range(len(D))):'` this python code in C++.... how to traversing the list in C++...

I think if i wanna traversing the three dimension vector in C++, it as same as print, so it should be three level loop..and like

```
for(int i; i < vector...emmmmmm; i++)
{
    for(int j; j< vector.....emmmm; j++)
    {
        for(int k; k < vector......; k++)
        {
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

have no idea...sorry

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> D = region_group(region_list);
int lend = D.size();
std::vector<int> N(2, 0);
std::vector<std::vector<int>> qua(4, N);
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>> quad_list(lend, qua);//quad_list((len(D),4,2))
std::vector<int> S(4, 0);
std::vector<std::vector<int>>score_list(lend, S); //score_list = np.zeros((len(D), 4))
```

here for the code `python for group,g_th in zip(D,range(len(D))):`

Please give me some hints about the operation of high dimension vector in C++.

Comment: The operations of high dimensional vectors are exactly the same as one dimensional vectors. They're all vectors. The only thing to remember is that the elements of a higher dimensional vector are themselves vectors.

Comment: So you want to iterate over 3 vectors but also retain the iteration indexes for each vector (like you would using `enumerate` in python)? The first code sample looks like you are pretty much there. You just need to replace the `vector.....emmmm` parts with references to real vectors.

Comment: You wouldn't use `zip` for that, you use `for index, element in enumerate(D):`

Comment: any easy way to replace the zip python function in C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to [boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/indexed.html) and [C++17](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), it's very similar to python

```
for i, e in enumerate(C): # more pythonic than zip(range(len(C)), C)
    ...
```

Becomes

```
using boost::adaptors::index;
for (auto [i, e] : index(C))
{
    ...
}
```

If you *really* want to have something similar to `zip(C, range(len(C)))`

```
for (auto [i, e] : boost::combine(boost::irange(C.size()), C))
```